# Counting simple closed curves

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory, riemann-surfaces, teichmuller-theory

I'm currently trying to understand how to count simple closed curves. I've been reading Alex Wright's survey (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1905.01753.pdf). However, I don't feel like I'm getting the big picture. All the surveys I can find on the subject try to show things in an explicit way, but I'd rather see an abstration. I feel the way dynamicist tacle this problem post Mirzakhani is by giving a flow on $M_{g,n}$, the Teichmüller geodesic flow. By the work of Mirzakhani, this is a ergodic flow. My question is how does this help us understand the function 
$$f_L:M_{g,n}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}, \quad X\mapsto s_X(L):=\{ \gamma \mid \ell(\gamma)\leq L\}?$$
I feel that estimates of this function should be related to the Ergodic Theorem, but I can not find anything on that.

PS: I'm sorry for the tags, but I'm uncertain which tags I should use.

Comment: It may be that the 2-page Introduction of this paper could help? Cahn, Patricia, Federica Fanoni, and Bram Petri. "Mapping class group orbits of curves with self-intersections." *Israel Journal of Mathematics* 223, no. 1 (2018): 53-74.
[arXiv abstract](https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.00846).